How can I print my own error to the screen when the user enters a string to the integer line
I want to show my own error to the screen insted of this ==>
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:964)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1619)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2284)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2238)

I want it like this if input enters a str or - number ==>
Please enter a valid number!
I tried this but it is not working but at least it's working for nil or - numbers but when I enter a string nothing is working
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
       int secondNum = scanner.nextInt();
       if(secondNum == 0 || firstNum == 0){
           System.out.print("Please enter a valid number!");
       } else if(firstNum > 0 && secondNum > 0){
           int add = Math.addExact(firstNum,secondNum);
           System.out.print(add);
       } else{
           System.out.print("Please enter a valid number!");
       }
    }
}


Learn about exception, try and catch. That'll do.

Ok got it I will give it a shot

probably easiest way is to use hasNextInt() to check if the next entry is an int before calling nextInt(), displaying the error if not - don't forget to consume the wrong input. Alternative: read the whole input line using nextLine() and then Integer.parseInt() it to get the integer

This question is similar to: Using try-catch java. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the instructions guys I really appreciate it. I finally did it here is the answer.
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
            int secondNum = scanner.nextInt();
            if(firstNum == 0 || secondNum == 0){
                System.out.print("inf");
            } else{
                System.out.print(firstNum/secondNum);
            }
        } catch(Exception c){
            System.out.print("Wrong Format");
        }
    }
}


It might be a bit different from the other answers but that is the answer that I wanted to get. Thanks again!

Catch InputMismatchException instead of Exception: otherwise the message could be misleading.

The issue with your code is that it will throw an InputMismatchException when you try to input a string using scanner.nextInt(). FOr this, you can use a try-catch block to catch the exception and display your custom error message. In the code below, the try block tries to read an integer from the user. If the user enters a non-integer value, an InputMismatchException is thrown, which is caught by the catch block. The catch block then prints your custom error message and clears the buffer using scanner.nextLine(). The loop continues until valid integers are entered.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0;
       boolean isValid = false;

       while(!isValid) {
           try {
               System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
               firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
               System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
               secondNum = scanner.nextInt();
               isValid = true;
           } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Please enter a valid number!");
               scanner.nextLine(); // clear the buffer
           }
       }

       if(firstNum <= 0 || secondNum <= 0){
           System.out.print("Please enter a number greater than 0!");
       } else {
           int add = Math.addExact(firstNum,secondNum);
           System.out.print("The sum is: " + add);
       }
    }
}

Output:
Enter first number: e
Please enter a valid number!
Enter first number: e
Please enter a valid number!
Enter first number: 2
Enter second number: 3
The sum is: 5


Instead of catching an exception, you can check beforehand: while(!scanner.hasNextInt()) { if(!scanner.hasNext()) System.exit(0); /* terminal closed */ System.err.println("Not an int: " + scanner.next()); } int number = scanner.nextInt();

@Holger Correct that's even better, thank you for the comment.
